# How can I generate events for Context Audit.General and DLP.All using apis?

Tags: ruby, httprequest, office365, office365api

How can I generate events for Context Audit? General and DLP. All using apis?

Basically, I'm interested in generating those type of events using the API.

Right now I’m getting the information of the content types using an API as it is shown on this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#start-a-subscription and my objective is to be able to generate events that trigger logs/events for Audit.General and DLP.All.

For example: for generating logs/events for contentType=Audit.AzureActiveDirectory I only had to create a new user through Microsoft graph API https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users and it was all, in that way I triggered events/information and I can query using request mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#start-a-subscription.

Basically, that is I want to do for Audit.General and DLP. All but I have not found a way to trigger those events.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: While we would like to (and maybe some day will) have this API/data set as part of Microsoft Graph, this is NOT part of Microsoft Graph. Looking to see if there is a different tag for you.